# Keeping a UILabel centered with changing contents and AutoLayout

Tags: ios6, autolayout

I have 2 views. A MapKitView and a UILabel. Auto Layout is on.

I want the MKView to take up the whole screen (this seems to work fine) and the UILabel to remain the auto distance from the bottom of the screen but centered horizontally. The UILabel contents are changed programatically and afterwards I am calling `sizeToFit`.

After calling `sizeToFit` on the UILabel then it is no longer centered - the width seems to be adjusted only from the right hand side (trailing edge) keeping the left hand side in a constant position.

My understanding is that I should be able to achieve what I want only by setting the right constraints in IB?

The constraints I have applied to the label are:

```
Height Equals: 32
Width Equals: 166
Bottom Space to: Superview Equals: Default
Align Center X to: Map View
```

Only the last one, "Align Center X" is a user constraint - the rest being IB supplied.

I have tried a number of things, though none with much understanding (presumably my problem!).

I have called `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO` on the label.
I have set the label's `autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`. I have tried setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to random values. Calling `needsUpdateConstraints` on the label. I tried putting the call to `sizeToFit` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

I have come to the conclusion I need a little more understanding how I should be approaching this. Is `sizeToFit` not the thing to be calling when Auto Layout is on? Do I need to prod Auto Layout in some way after calling `sizeToFit`? I notice that rotating the simulator seems to center the label so prodding sounds a possibility?

I have re-read the [Apple Auto Layout guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1) but I'm afraid I'm still not sure what I am doing wrong and the debugging tips suggested (visualizeConstraints etc) don't seem to work on iOS.

Thanks for any clue you can spare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea about having to prod appears to be correct. After calling `sizeToFit` I needed to call `[label.superview setNeedsLayout]`. Whilst this works I'm not really sure why I need to do this manually rather than the label marking the layout as dirty when it's size changes.